# Computing with sparse matrix in scipy Python

Tags: arrays, numpy, matrix, scipy

I'm trying to implement the stopping criterion [described in this paper](http://www.math.kent.edu/~reichel/publications/rlt.pdf) in a Richardson-Lucy deconvolution algorithm. My test image has 2.2 Mpx. I need to compute :

```
estimator = numpy.dot(P_e_ortho, im_deconv.flatten())
```

where

```
im_deconv = [[]] # Image L channel as a 2D array
m = 2.2E6 # im_deconv.size

P_e_ortho = scipy.sparse.identity(m, dtype='int8') - \
            1/m * np.ones((m, m), dtype='int8')
```

So basically, `P_e_ortho` has `1 - 1/m` on the diagonal and `- 1/m` elsewhere.

Now this code returns a memory error (4.8×10¹² cells required). How could I avoid dealing with the whole square matrix in the computation ?

```
scipy.sparse.identity(m, dtype='int8') * (1 - 1/m)
```

works fine to set the diagonal, but how to change non-diagonal elements ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found :

```
# Construct a Row-based linked list sparse matrix
P_e_ortho = scipy.sparse.lil_matrix((m, m)) 

P_e_ortho[:, :] = -1/m # Sets all elements
P_e_ortho.setdiag(1-1/m) # Sets the diagonal
P_e_ortho = P_e_ortho.tocsr() # Convert to Compressed Sparse Row matrix

estimator = P_e_ortho.dot(im_deconv.flatten()) # Compute the dot product
```

Comment: I'm surprised this doesn't give you a memory error.  You have set all elements of matrix to nonzero values.  Total storage will be larger than the corresponding dense array, though split in to several arrays.  The `.dot` will also be much slower.

Comment: @hpaulj yes, it does not work for this problem and I gave up on this approach. The paper shows an implementation of this technic on small pictures, it's not really feasible on bigger ones. I switched to regularisation factors instead. But the solution is still valid to build the sparse matrix.